# Chrome saying that manifest.json is not in utf8

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm sure that it is I tried with/without BOM and I still get this error :
[image: UT8 Chrome Extension error]

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "default_locale": "en",

  "name":           "__MSG_ext_name__",
  "description":    "__MSG_ext_description__",
  "version":        "1.6.0",

  "icons": {
    "16":  "icon_16.png",
    "48":  "icon_48.png",
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon":  "icon_19.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },

  "options_page": "options.html",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "scripts/content.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what editor are you using?

Comment: Is your messages.json UTF-8?

Comment: I used notepad, then sublime text, then notepad++, to try to convert it to UTTF-8.

Comment: Solved, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a program [to mass convert all my files in UTF-8](https://www.google.fr/search?newwindow=1&safe=off&q=mass%20convert%20utf%208), now it works, I think as 方 觉 said, the problem was coming from another file than the manifest.